# Rabbitmq: exchange->routingkey->queue naming structure

Tags: c#, python, rabbitmq

I am using a direct exchange as I want one job to go to one consumer.

There are different groups of consumers who will consumer different jobs. Lets say my application is called "foo". I then have jobs

- bar1
- bar2
- bar3....

There will be a group of separate consumers to handle "bar1" jobs, then another group of consumers for "bar2" etc

I have tried to find out whether there are benefits to any particular naming / routing structure but not found anything to point to one way or another

***Question 1)***
Should I use multiple exchange names
Exchanges:

- exc_bar1
- exc_bar2
- exc_bar3

Or would a single exchange be best
Exchange:

- exc_foo

then use routing keys to send to correct consumer queue
RoutingKeys

- rk_bar1
- rk_bar2
- rk_bar3

I have not been able to find out anything either way, so I assume it doesn't really matter, but thought best to ask just incase I have missed something and it does matter.

---

**Background Info**

Just incase it is relevant

The producer is a python webapp, using the rabbitpy library
The consumers are c# applications using the default rabbitmq client library

The producer can set the 
 * Exchange name
 * Routing Key name

The consumer can set
 * Exchange name
 * routing key name
 * Queue name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, I would recommend using a single *exchange* to contain all the jobs for the single application, and then use a *queue* to represent each job type, which can then have multiple *consumers* (which will then be able to process messages from that queue in a round-robin fashion).

The *routing key* can then be used to direct the *consumers* in terms of which *job* they are processing.

Having only one exchange both makes sense as a logical grouping (i.e. at the app level) and simplifies management/administration/monitoring within *RabbitMQ*. If you have a new job type, you would need to simply create a new queue & binding and change the routing key, as opposed to having to create a new exchange and then also having to create a new queue & binding.

If later you have an entirely different application, then I would say it's time to create a new *exchange* for it and then follow the same general model I mention above (assuming it's similarly behaved from a high level).

I think the [*Routing* tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html) on the *RabbitMQ* website would probably fit your scenario  best, if you're looking for additional details (link below is for *Python* but they have one for *C#* also).